# Render a partial in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, partials

I want to render a partial with locals from a controller. I can't find the syntax for this anywhere (neither Rails docs on partials / views or googling).

I could have this action's view only contain a partial, but that sounds like an extra layer of complexity that I'd like to avoid. Using (controller -> partial) instead of (controller -> action's view -> partial) seems cleaner. Maybe my intuition is wrong?

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

```
def show
  render 'some_partial', locals: { test => 'hello' }
end
```

Gives the error:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 2..3)
```

Comment: Can you post the error stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partials should be rendered from a template or a layout, they are partial views not full views, update the show.html.erb to render whatever partial needs to be shown

If you truly want to render a partial then try

```
render :partial => 'some_partial', :locals => { :test => "hello" }
```

Or for the newer Rails 4 syntax

```
render partial: 'some_partial', locals: { test: "Hello" }
```